# application of minimize_scalar

Tags: scipy, minimization

I am trying to replicate the results posted here ([How to use scipy.optimize minimize_scalar when objective function has multiple arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422845/how-to-use-scipy-optimize-minimize-scalar-when-objective-function-has-multiple-a)) using a different structure. The goal is exactly the same but I just want to code it in a different way. Here is my code:

```
def mini(g,a,b,args):
  object=lambda w1: g(w1, *args)
  result=minimize_scalar(object, bounds=(a, b))
  minzer, minval=result.x, result.fun
  return minzer,minval

def errorr(w0,w1,x,y):
  y_pred = w0 + w1*x
  mse = ((y-y_pred)**2).mean()
  return mse

x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([52,54,56])
w0=50

mini(errorr, -5, 5, (w0,x,y))
```

However, the results obtained using my code is quite different from the one in the original posts. I am wondering where did I make the mistake in my code that caused the different results. Thanks!

Comment: I'm too lazy to examine the link and identify what you are doing different.  And without copying all the code and running it I have no idea what's different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `lambda w1: g(w1, *args)`, you are minimizing with respect to the first function argument `w0`. To minimize with respect to `w1`, you can write `lambda w1: g(args[0], w1, *args[1:])` instead.

However, please avoid python keywords as variable names (e.g. `object`). In addition, a lambda function is an anonymous function, so assigning it to a variable contradicts its purpose. Consequently, I'd propose either

```py
def mini(g,a,b,args):
    def obj_fun(w1): return g(args[0], w1, *args[1:]) 
    result = minimize_scalar(obj_fun, bounds=(a, b))
    return result.x, result.fun
```

or

```py
def mini(g,a,b,args):
    result = minimize_scalar(lambda w1: g(args[0], w1, *args[1:]), bounds=(a, b))
    return result.x, result.fun
```

Comment: Thanks! since I am very new to python, could you please share where I can find the document that explains "Since you use lambda w1: g(w1, *args), you are minimizing with respect to the first function argument w0"

Comment: The function `lambda w1: g(w1, *args)` evaluates `g` for the first argument while unpacking all following function arguments `args`. When passing `errorr` for `g`, the first argument is `w0` and you have `w1, x, y = args`. Note that this behaviour is independent of the variable name, i.e. it would be the same for `lambda x: g(x, *args)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! Now I understand!